# Delete unpersisted record

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I wonder what's the procedure to delete a non persisted record.

I have a domain that has many redirections

I start to create a redirection with

```
domain = @modelFor('domain')
redirection = @store.createRecord('redirection')
domain.get('redirections').pushObject(redirection)
```

is this correct ? And how to delete the redirection object if my user click on cancel button ?

I've tried this but that does not work.

```
redirection = @get('model')
redirection.rollback()
redirection.unloadRecord()
```

I'm using ember and ember-data both in canary version.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do

```
redirection = @get('model')
@store.deleteRecord(redirection)
```

Comment: Unfortunately the record is still shown in the redirections list.

Comment: Try adding `domain.get('redirections').removeObject(redirection)` and `redirection.save()` if you want to persist the deleted state to your server

Comment: Yep it works. I hope that ember-data will soon get less tricky :-) Thanks.